# find the eigenvalues find the associated eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

Define $\alpha \in End(\mathbb{R}^3)$ by $\alpha: \begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b\\
c
\end{bmatrix} \mapsto \begin{bmatrix}
a-b\\
a+2b+c\\
-2a+b-c
\end{bmatrix}$.
Find the eigenvalues of $\alpha$ and, for each eigenvalue, find the associated eigenspace.

Comment: What is the top row? Well $a + b = 1a + 1b + 0c$, which means that:

$$\alpha = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 0 \\
    ? & ? & ? \\
    ? & ? & ?
\end{bmatrix}$$

Can you find the rest of the matrix and compute the eigenvalues and eigenspace from that?

Comment: not sure. please provide a bit more info

Comment: are you using the standard basis?  could use a bit more info please.

Comment: Yes, I am using the standard basis.

Comment: im not really sure what you are doing here..could you please provide a little more insight into whats going on

Comment: \alpha = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & 0 \\     1 & 2 & 1 \\     -2 & 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix} \\ this is what I got using the standard basis...now i find the eigenspace?